# My node server is running fine in docker with my nginx but it can't find the react's files

Tags: reactjs, node.js, docker, docker-compose

I'm quite new to docker, and I'm trying to have a Symfony app with docker and ReactJS.

I succeed in running Symfony with a Nginx server and php with Docker, but when I run a node server, it says that the webpack is successfully compiled in the docker console but when I go to the homepage it says it can't find the files.

However, when I run Nginx and php with Docker but run node on local with `npm run dev-server` everything works as intended.

When I compare the message from the two console I find them the same so I don't know why it can find the files on local but can't with docker.

##### docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"

name: test-samuel

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www:delegated
      - ./tools/docker/web/config.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    links:
      - php


  php:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: lucasluk798/php:8.2
    
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www:delegated
    environment:
      - APP_ENV=dev

  mailer:
    image: schickling/mailcatcher
    ports: [1025, 1080]

  database:
      image: 'mysql:8.0'
      environment:
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
          MYSQL_DATABASE: todo-Symfony
      ports:
          - '3306'
      volumes:
          - db_data:/var/lib/mysql

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3080:80
    environment:
      - PMA_ARBITRARY=1

  encore:
    image: node:latest
    volumes:
        - .:/var/www
    working_dir: /var/www
    command: >
        sh -c "npm install &&
                npm run dev-server"
    ports:
        - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - SERVER_PORT=8080

volumes:
  db_data: {}

networks:
  dev:
```

##### webpack.config.js

```js
const Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

// Manually configure the runtime environment if not already configured yet by the "encore" command.
// It's useful when you use tools that rely on webpack.config.js file.
if (!Encore.isRuntimeEnvironmentConfigured()) {
    Encore.configureRuntimeEnvironment(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'dev');
}

Encore
    // directory where compiled assets will be stored
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    // public path used by the web server to access the output path
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    // only needed for CDN's or subdirectory deploy
    //.setManifestKeyPrefix('build/')

    /*
     * ENTRY CONFIG
     *
     * Each entry will result in one JavaScript file (e.g. app.js)
     * and one CSS file (e.g. app.css) if your JavaScript imports CSS.
     */
    .addEntry('app', './assets/app.js')

    // When enabled, Webpack "splits" your files into smaller pieces for greater optimization.
    .splitEntryChunks()

    // will require an extra script tag for runtime.js
    // but, you probably want this, unless you're building a single-page app
    .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()


    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    // enables hashed filenames (e.g. app.abc123.css)
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())


    // enables and configure @babel/preset-env polyfills
    .configureBabelPresetEnv((config) => {
        config.useBuiltIns = 'usage';
        config.corejs = '3.23';
    })

    // uncomment if you use React
    .enableReactPreset()

;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

##### 404 errors in chrome console

[404 errors in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yH2m8.png)

I tried doing `npm run watch` or `npm run dev` in my docker-compose which resulted in no 404 errors as it builded the files, but if I changed my js files to change the text for exemple I needed to do `docker-compose down` and then `docker-compose up` for building the files again

Also, when I go on localhost:8080 while node is runned by docker, I got a 404 whereas if node is runned locally and I go to localhost:8080 I got a "cannot GET /" which is the correct answer

Thanks all for your help